# Translate laravel 5 Bcrypt

Tags: bcrypt, laravel-5

How to translate laravel Bcrypt password to plain text ? I want to use this when users forgot their password, and send the plain password to their email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not translate laravel Bcrypt password to plain text.
 Becuase bcrypt is hash .
For reset password in laravel 5.2 you can see this link
[reset password](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#resetting-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old - and the thing Hendrik is trying to do is not even possible -  but I stumbled across it and have to add, in case anyone else is wanting to do this:

**Don't try to override the things that are keeping your users' data safe.**

passwords should never be plain text (*so that only your user - and not any random who happens to have access to your db - knows their password*)

passwords should never be sent by email (*so that only your user - and not any random who happens to gain access to their email - knows their password*)

Passwords are hashed specifically to protect your users' data. That's a good thing.